# Parse Cloud Code Save Not Performing.

Tags: javascript, json, parse-platform

I was working on a piece of cloud code (Parse) for my IOS application and noticed that it wouldn't work whenever I tried to save the updated object. If I remove the save function, the code works and prints out the the success response, but if I keep it in I get the error:

`Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}`

I've tried out a bunch of solutions and regardless of what they are, the error message above still gets printed from the X-Code debugger IF the save function is in the code. (If not then it prints the success response)

This is the code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("removeFriend", function(request, response) {
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
var userObjId = request.params.userObjId;
var currentUser = request.params.currentUser;
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
query.equalTo("objectId", userObjId);
//query.include('Friends');
query.find({
    success: function(results){
        var friendsArray = (results[0].get("Friends"));
        var newFriends = friendsArray.filter(function(x) {return x != currentUser});

        results[0].set("Friends", newFriends);
        results[0].save();
        response.success("THIS IS RESULT" + results[0].get("Friends"));



    },
    error: function(){
        response.error("The user was not successfully removed.");   

    }   
});

});
```

(I created a similar question with the same error earlier but have redone the code since then so I didn't want to mix the two questions up.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saves are asynchronous, meaning they happen in a separate thread.  You are returning with `response.success()` right after calling `save()`, so the save never completes before the function terminates.

You have two options: Add success / error options to the `save()` call, or use promises. I prefer the latter, it enables much cleaner code when you get the hang of them.

```
results[0].save().then(
    function( success ) {
        response.success("THIS IS RESULT" + results[0].get("Friends"));
    },
    function( error ) { 
        response.error("There was an error trying to save the object: " + JSON.stringify(error)); 
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem and helped me understand what was actually causing the problem in the first place.

Comment: No problem. An important part that I left out - asynchronasity / running on a separate thread itself isn't the problem, but that the function running on the other thread is a server call, which takes time to finish. Your server hits that response call almost immediately, so there's no time for the asynchronous operation to complete. You'll have the same issue with http requests, fetches, queries, destroys, and calling other cloud functions.

Comment: Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey(); has been deprecated in Parse Server version 2.3.0 (Dec 7, 2016). From that version on, it is a no-op (it does nothing). You should now insert the {useMasterKey:true} optional parameter to each of the methods that need to override the ACL or CLP in your code.